# Shelah notation

Tags: logic, set-theory, predicate-logic, model-theory

Does someone know what is $K^{\frak s}$ [here](https://shelah.logic.at/papers/705/) at the bottom of 2nd page? It is quite frequent in the text but I cannot locate the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the text itself, it's an a.e.c. i.e. an [abstract elementary class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_elementary_class). (You should find this confirmed the third time that initialism is used.)

Comment: OK. And how this literally differs from $\frak K_s$ in the line before $K^\frak s$?

Comment: That's a $\lambda_s$-a.e.c., according to the same sentence. By the way, how do you get that k? Please type it again between backticks instead of dollar signs (or without wrapper symbols at all).

Comment: Sorry my English is poor. What do you want me to type again? \frak K_s ?

Comment: How is $\lambda_{\frak s}$-a.e.c. different from a.e.c.?

Comment: With braces that gives me $\frak{K_s}$ - yes, that's it, thanks! Unfortunately, I don't know enough about this subject to explain $\lambda_s$-a.e.cs.

Comment: Fine. It is on the page 20 [here](http://shelah.logic.at/files/600.pdf).